# translating a string using key-value from dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

This function takes a dictionary as an argument and translates the given string. However, it has become an endless loop. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it work normally. For example: it is supposed to take a string "hi" and translates it into "[-]1"

```
def translate(glyphs):
    string = input("Enter string to be translated: ").strip()
    new = ''
    for keys in glyphs:
        ind = string.upper().find(keys)
        while ind != -1: #while there exists a key in the string
            if len(glyphs[string[ind].upper()]) > 1: #if there is more than one value for key
                rand = randint(0, 1) #choose randomly
                transChar = glyphs[keys][rand]
                new = string[:ind] + transChar + string[ind+1:]
                ind = string.upper().find(keys)
                print("hi1")
            else:
                transChar = glyphs[keys][0]
                new = string[:ind] + transChar + string[ind+1:]
                ind = string.upper().find(keys)
                print("hi")
    return new
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `new = ' '.join([glyphs.get(i, i) for i in input_string.split()])` ?

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @boardrider thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your dictionary contains lists of possible translations as values, from which you make random choices, and upper-case keys. This list comprehension should work, then:

```
import random

new = ' '.join(random.choice(glyphs[word]) \
               for word in input_string.upper().split())
```

Comment: how do i iterate over each character in string instead of word? The keys in the dictionary replaces "H" with "[-]" and "I" with "1"